# C++ char* x = fgets() don't work

Tags: c++

My script in C++ give me this result without any errors:

1
2
Press any key to continue...

This is my program:

```
    const char* fileName = "kwerendy.txt";
    FILE * file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    while (! feof(file))
    {
        printf("1\n");
        char* row;
        printf("2\n");
        fgets(row, 1000, file);
        printf("3\n");
        int i = 0;
        printf("4\n");
        cout << "TEXT (line[" << i << "]): " << row;
    }
```

Have you any ideas, because I don't know how to repair this.

Comment: `row` doesn't point to anything, you're not writing to a valid location. And why are you using `printf` and `fopen` with C++?

Comment: I used printf only for testing how it work's and fopen, because I' m prescribing code from php. If I put equal sign after row (something like this: row = fgets) my code result is 1 after this program stops.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how C++ works :/


Here is my program in C++:
https://hastebin.com/xovimuxiwa.cpp

And here in PHP:
https://hastebin.com/uyepazowaq.xml

Comment: don't use feof in a loop condition  (especially not in C++ but I don't think it's a good idea in other languages either)

Comment: @M.M Could you write me why this isn't a good practice? What are the consequences using this in c++?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Answer (score 2):

`row` is not assigned a value, so you are writing to an arbitrary memory address--that's very bad. It's undefined behavior and even if it works now it is likely to fail in the future. You need to allocate space for the characters that `fgets` reads. Or you could declare `row` as a static array:

```
char row[buffer_size];
fgets(row, buffer_size, file);
```

A better way would be to use an `ifstream` with `string`s:

```
std::ifstream file(fileName);
std::string line;
int i = 0;
while (getline(file, line)) {
    std::cout << "TEXT (line[" << i++ << "]): "
              << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and last question. How can I use string type of value, because I don't get it? When I change char to string I've an error that says I can not convert char to string value: "error: cannot convert 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)'
         fgets(row, 100, file);"

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example of how to do it the C++ way, see above.

Comment: Thank you so much.